# How to resolve a conflict with git-svn?

Tags: git, svn, merge, conflict

What is the best way to resolve a conflict when doing a `git svn rebase`, and the git branch you are on becomes "(no-branch)"?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `git mergetool` to view and edit the conflicts in the usual fashion. Once you are sure the conflicts are resolved do `git rebase --continue` to continue the rebase, or if you don't want to include that revision do `git rebase --skip`

Comment: This helped, thanks.  So others don't have my problem.... let `mergetool` stage your changes, but don't `commit` them.  Simply call `git rebase --continue` with your staged changes.

Answer (score 90):

While doing a `git svn rebase`, if you have merge conflicts here are some things to remember:

**1)** If anything bad happens while performing a rebase you will end up on a `(no-branch)` branch.

**2)** If you run `git status`, you'll see a `.dotest` file in your working directory. This is safe to ignore.

**3)** If you want to abort the rebase use the following command.<sup>1</sup>

```
git rebase --abort
```

**4)** If you have a merge conflict:

1. Manually edit the files to resolve the conflicts
2. Stage any changes with `git add [file]`
3. Continue the rebase with `git rebase --continue`<sup>2</sup>

   - If git asks: "did you forget to call `git add`?", then the edits turned the conflict into a no-op change<sup>3</sup>. Continue with `git rebase --skip`

You may have to repeat this process until the rebase is complete. At any point you can `git rebase --abort` to cancel and abandon the rebase.

---

<sub>1: There is no `--abort` option for `git svn rebase`.</sub>

<sub>2: There is no `--continue` option for `git svn rebase`.</sub>

<sub>3: This is very strange, but the files are in a state where git thinks they are the same after that particular patch. The solution is to "skip"
 that patch on the rebase.</sub>

Comment: just got hit with the no-op change thing, really odd

Comment: Thanks for the --skip tip, didn't even consider it.

Comment: The whole git rebase --skip thing caused me a bit of grief since I ended up losing my changes quite a few times in my attempts to resolve the conflict. In hindsight I probably should have made a local branch and put my changes in that instead of relying on git stash. I didn't do so because I had read that there are problems with merging branches in git svn, but I think that's to do with trying to merge *svn* branches that you replicate in your local git copy.

Comment: I did a merge from remote/trunk into our team's working branch, and I ended up having to resolve the conflicts twice, once on merge, then again when I did a 'git svn rebase'.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: I know that this is old question, but I hope someone will answer. I imported svn repo using `git svn`. Once made some changes under `git`, but people still work on `svn` so I have to fetch their changes. Everytime I do `git svn rebase` I have to go through this whole process of resolving same "conflicts". How to avoid that? `rerere`did not help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @csexton your link to harrys blog is dead