# Rebasing a Detached HEAD against a master branch

Tags: git, merge, rebase, gerrit

I use gerrit at my job, and it requires use of rebase instead of merge commits. Today I checked out a previous commit using its hash value, and when I ran the git branch command, I was informed I was on "no branch". I assume this is a detached HEAD? In any case, I rebased against my my master branch, and the console printed

```
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
```

Where does the '3-way merge' in this situation come from? And was the HEAD still detached after the rebase (considering the 'base-tree' statement)? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes 'no branch' means *detached HEAD*

The base revision comes from doing

```
git merge-base <yourrevision> master
```

It will look at the last common ancestor (or merge point, which is considered a common ancestor even if there were manual conflicts) to establish a base version.

After a rebase, you are normally always on a new detached HEAD, IIRC. Now there are numerous ways in which to call rebase (including --onto --root) and they may behave slightly differently. So if you care to post the rebase command used, I may verify my thinking and perhaps add some comments.

Comment: A rebase does detach HEAD, but it gets reattached when it completes.

Comment: For some reason in my case it usually ends up deatached after completed... i get some permission denied stuff from time to time and so have to use --continue.

I usually say rebase -i HEAD~10, for squashing the last commits. Any idea why it wouldnt attach itself back?

Comment: Usually because of merge conflicts (possible pseudo conflicts). You need to `merge-tool` and `add`, then `rebase --continue` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112839/how-to-resolve-a-conflict-with-git-svn/112859#112859)

Answer (score 0):

As [illustrated here](http://epx.com.br/artigos/gitfaces.php), this error message is usually the sign of a conflict:

> The conflict does not go away by itself, but in this case we fix the conflict and continue, and the original patch "Added another message" will be itself changed:

```
$ vi main.c
$ git add main.c
$ git rebase --continue
```

The key is to *continue* the rebase after fixing the conflict.